# AddorUpdate data in dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am caching items and storing it in dictionary and then now i am fetching delta items.
So i want to add or update when the deltas are detected.

I tried the below code but it is not working.

```
   foreach(var item in companies)
                {

                    _cache.Cacheditem.AddOrUpdate(item.Id,item,(_cache.Cacheditem.Values.Where(x=>x.Id==item.Id).FirstOrDefault().Id,
                        _cache.Cacheditem.Values.Where(x => x.Id == item.Id)) => {
                        return item;
                    });
    
                }
```

Could you guide me how do i update or add the item the item into cache, Cached item has multiple list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of detail here to work with - and a number of potential issues. I will assume for the sake of answering your question that _cache.Cacheditem is a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1). I will also initially assume that you have thoroughly considered your application architecture and there is a good reason for writing your code this way. If not then you may be able to gain significant performance and maintenance improvements by restructuring your code instead.

If all you want to do is to ensure that the data in your dictionary contains the latest values, you can simply write

```
_cache.CachedItem[item.Id] = item;
```

If you want more advanced logic to detect a change and take some action when a change is detected you could try

```
_cache.CachedItem.AddOrUpdate(item.Id, item, (id, oldValue) =>
{
  if (oldValue.Equals(item))
  {
    return oldValue;
  }
  else
  {
    //change detected. Do something here
    return item;
  }
});
```

A couple of notes:

1. Unless you are comparing structs, you will almost definitely want to write and use your own "Equals" function to determine object equality between the old cached item and the new uncached item. This is because unless the object is a [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types), object equality (==) is determined by the object reference and not the object value ([link](https://coding.abel.nu/2014/09/net-and-equals/)).
2. If your cached object is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) and is potentially referenced in other places in your code, you may want to consider extending it with the new properties instead of replacing it. Otherwise old references will still remain and will contain the old values instead of the new - not to mention the very real potential for creating memory issues.

Comment: yes it is concurrent dictionary. But how will it get the old value and Id here. (id, oldValue). So how is the Id and oldvalue referenced here

Comment: The id and oldValue are parameters that will be provided to your function if the cached object is found [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate?view=netcore-3.1). The general idea is that the dictionary will do a simple insert if the key is not found in the dictionary, but will execute your custom logic on the existing value if they key is found, then replace the cached value with the object returned from that function.

Comment: This addorupdate is not working for me. The code is breaking.